# Offering WP-Members and Facebook login options together seamlessly

Tags: mysql, facebook, wordpress

I am starting a website and activated WP-Members for my user registration/login. This is great because I can then easily capture `user_id` in the MySQL table for writing my queries. But I am thinking I probably should also offer Facebook login or maybe even the Social Connect plugin as well.

The problem I'm guessing is that facebook login or any such social media login will use a different variable for `user_id` (such as fb_login) and so users who login this way will not be placed in the same Members table as users who login with WP-Members. Therefore, I'm not sure the easiest way to go about offering both registration methods.

Is it just too complex to do in general for a newbie to make both registration options establish users in the same table or at least make it easy for me to reference `user_id` for both methods when trying to run user-id conditional statements and such?

Comment: Please can you clarify your problem.

Comment: It's more of a question of how a regular membership plug with a users table works alongside a facebook login plugin. I'd like to offer both but it seems like there would be no way to have one universal members table if I use both options. Is that correct? I am wondering how when people login with Facebook they could be assigned a user name that would go in the same user_id table as people who login without facebook. Is this common?

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I'm guessing is that facebook login or any such social
>   media login will use a different variable for user_id (such as
>   fb_login) and so users who login this way will not be placed in the
>   same Members table as users who login with WP-Members.

Unless a membership plugin creates and uses its own user table, all users are saved in the same table in WordPress - `wp_users`.  Altering that would severely restrict your ability to integrate with other plugins and/or WordPress itself since you'd be trying to manage two separate user tables.

That isn't really the problem you're facing, but I wanted to mention it because in order to address your issue, your mindset has to understand [the db schema you are working with](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description).

WP-Members uses the WP db schema so that it will maintain compatibility not only with WordPress, but also with other plugins.  There is not need to separate login/registration using a separate table (in fact, I'd advise against that).  There are WP-Members users who use Social Connect just fine. They can be integrated because they rely on the same database.